# Force immutability and create instance in the interface declaration

Tags: java, api, oop, interface

I have an interface that its API are only getter methods thereby ensuring that the class that implements the interface is in that respect immutable.
But if I need to update something that changes the behavior of the interface how would I declare my interface so that it creates a new instance of the concrete class?
Right now I have something like:

```
    public interface Generator {  
      public int[] values();  
      public float[] indications();  
      //etc  
      public MyEnum type;  
    }  

    public class ConcreteClass implements Generator {  
      private ConcreteClass() {  
      }  
      public static ConcreteClass createInstance() {  

       }  
   }
```

I have omitted arguments for clarity.
How would I move the `createInstance` to the interface?

Answer (score 0):

An interface is not designed to have implementation. With Java 8 you could have default method but it would be a bad idea that interface knows the implementation classes. An interface should stay abstract and not know its subclasses.

If `ConcreteClass` is immutable, you should document it and ensure that each method with side-effect doesn't apply any modification on the current object but instead create a new instance of `ConcreteClass`.

For example suppose you want provide method to update the `values` field, you could provide this method in `ConcreteClass` :

```
public ConcreteClass withValues(int[] values){
   // copy all existing properties from the original to the copy but values
   ConcreteClass copy = new ConcreteClass(values, this.indications, this.type);    
   return copy;
}
```

If you want really move out the instance creation from `ConcreteClass`, you could create a factory that provides this service.

Comment: I was considering if moving the `createInstance()` as part of the interface declaration a good design approach or not. I would only define the method and not the actual implementation

Comment: Adding a abstract method in the interface to create a new instance assumes that the interface knows the constraints implementations (such as the required fields)  and it is not a good idea either because it couples the interface to the implementation. Only the reverse should be true.

Comment: Then when I say that the interface defines something that is immutable that is not correct either? Thereby doesn't really matter if I add a setter?

Comment: Indeed. The interface cannot define it itself. It can be documented to be designed to be immutable but only the implementation can make the concrete class immutable or not. You are not forced to add a setter if you want to keep the implementation immutable. In my answer I show a way to create a new instance when a side effect operation (such as a setter) is invoked.

Comment: The thing is that this works for classes that are aware of the `ConcreteClass`. But my interest is for all uses that are aware only the `Generator` reference

Comment: In this case using factory is more appropiated. In the factory, methods should manipulate the interface as declared types.